# Union on empty Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have function

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Document>> GetDocuments(...)
```

in which I search for documents under some given conditions. Some conditions can be skipped. At the end I perform union of these queries.

```
   var documents = await documentService.GetDocuments(this, userId,
                roleShowFullNumber, param.OrderColName(), param.SearchValue, filter);
  var usersGroupsId = filter.UsersGroupsId;
        if (usersGroupsId != null)
        {
            if (!usersGroupsId.Contains("All"))
            {
                IQueryable<Document> myDocs = Enumerable.Empty<Document>().AsQueryable();
                if (usersGroupsId.Contains("myOrders"))
                {
                    myDocs = documents.Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId || x.UserId == userId);
                    usersGroupsId = usersGroupsId.Where(x => x != "myOrders").ToArray();
                }
                IQueryable<Document> wards = Enumerable.Empty<Document>().AsQueryable();
                if (usersGroupsId.Contains("wards"))
                {
                    var relatedUserId = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(x => x.RelatedUserId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (relatedUserId != null)
                    {
                        var myWards = _db.kh__Kontrahent.Where(x => x.kh_IdOpiekun == relatedUserId);
                        var myWardsUsers = _db.Users.Where(x => myWards.Any(w => w.kh_Id == (x.RelatedCustomerId == null ? -1 : x.RelatedCustomerId)));
                        wards = documents.Where(x => (myWardsUsers.Any(w => x.UserId == w.Id) || myWardsUsers.Any(w => x.OwnerId == w.Id)));
                        usersGroupsId = usersGroupsId.Where(x => x != "wards").ToArray();
                    }
                }

                IQueryable<Document> groups = Enumerable.Empty<Document>().AsQueryable();
                if (usersGroupsId.Length > 0)
                {
                    var usersGroups = _db.Groups.Where(x => usersGroupsId.Contains(x.Id.ToString()));
                    var usersList = usersGroups.Select(x => x.Users);
                    var users = usersList.SelectMany(x => x);
                    var usersId = users.Select(x => x.Id);
                    groups = _db.Documents.Where(x => (usersId.Any(u => u == x.OwnerId) || usersId.Any(u => u == x.UserId)));
                }

                documents = myDocs.Union(wards).Union(groups);

            }
        }
```

But if one of these partial queries is empty (was skipped) when I try obtain these documents in way shown below I got error.

```
   var documentsPaginated = await documents.Skip(param.Start)
                                    .Take(param.Length)
                                    .ToListAsync();
```

Error: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable.

How can I make this function to be able to skip some sub queries and then union all. I would prefer not to change function return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, althought your code seems to have a massive amount of code smell...

```
public async Task<IQueryable<Document>> GetDocuments(...)      
   var documents = await documentService.GetDocuments(this, userId,
                roleShowFullNumber, param.OrderColName(), param.SearchValue, filter);
  var usersGroupsId = filter.UsersGroupsId;
        if (usersGroupsId != null)
        {
            if (!usersGroupsId.Contains("All"))
            {
                IQueryable<Document> myDocs = null;
                if (usersGroupsId.Contains("myOrders"))
                {
                    myDocs = documents.Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId || x.UserId == userId);
                    usersGroupsId = usersGroupsId.Where(x => x != "myOrders").ToArray();
                }
                IQueryable<Document> wards = null;
                if (usersGroupsId.Contains("wards"))
                {
                    var relatedUserId = _db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Select(x => x.RelatedUserId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (relatedUserId != null)
                    {
                        var myWards = _db.kh__Kontrahent.Where(x => x.kh_IdOpiekun == relatedUserId);
                        var myWardsUsers = _db.Users.Where(x => myWards.Any(w => w.kh_Id == (x.RelatedCustomerId == null ? -1 : x.RelatedCustomerId)));
                        wards = documents.Where(x => (myWardsUsers.Any(w => x.UserId == w.Id) || myWardsUsers.Any(w => x.OwnerId == w.Id)));
                        usersGroupsId = usersGroupsId.Where(x => x != "wards").ToArray();
                    }
                }

                IQueryable<Document> groups = null;
                if (usersGroupsId.Length > 0)
                {
                    var usersGroups = _db.Groups.Where(x => usersGroupsId.Contains(x.Id.ToString()));
                    var usersList = usersGroups.Select(x => x.Users);
                    var users = usersList.SelectMany(x => x);
                    var usersId = users.Select(x => x.Id);
                    groups = _db.Documents.Where(x => (usersId.Any(u => u == x.OwnerId) || usersId.Any(u => u == x.UserId)));
                }
                if(myDocs != null)
                    documents = documents.Union(myDocs);
                if(wards != null)
                    documents = documents.Union(wards);
                if(groups != null)
                    documents = documents.Union(groups);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, did't think of that:)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ToListAsync can't be used interchangeably with linq, but only in an EF query.

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn313107.aspx)

> Entity Framework 6 introduced a set of extension methods that can be used to asynchronously execute a query. Examples of these methods include ToListAsync, FirstAsync, ForEachAsync, etc.
>
> Because Entity Framework queries make use of LINQ, the extension methods are defined on IQueryable and IEnumerable. However, because they are only designed to be used with Entity Framework you may receive the following error if you try to use them on a LINQ query that isn’t an Entity Framework query.
>
> The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable{0}. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

Comment: So what empty query should I assign to these empty subqueries so I could perform union even if they are skipped?